# Finding chance of winning $A$ is in a alternate throw a fair coin.

Tags: probability

> $A$ and $B$ alternately throw a pair of coin. The player who throws head two times first will win.
>
> A has the first throw. The find chance of winning $A$ is

Attempt: Let $\displaystyle P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$ (Probability of occuring head when  $A$ throw coin) and

$\displaystyle P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$ (Probability of occuring head when  $A$ throw coin)

So chance of winning  $A$ when he throw head 1st time  is $$\displaystyle P(A)+P(A)P(\bar{B})P(A)+P(\bar{A})P(\bar{B})P(\bar{A})P(\bar{B})P(A)+\cdots \cdots$$

could some help me how to go for original question, thanks

Comment: Supposing $A$ wins on his $k$'th turn $(k\geq 2)$, that means in his previous $k-1$ turns, he has thrown head exactly once and has thrown tails $k-2$ times and on the $k$'th throw he has thrown heads.  Meanwhile player $B$ has either thrown all tails or has thrown heads once in his $k-1$ turns.  The probability then that player $A$ wins on his $k$'th turn is... and adding up over all possible values of $k$ this implies the probability that $A$ is the eventual winner is...

Comment: The header reads "... alternate throw a fair coin", while the body reads "alternately throw a **pair** of coin" Pl. clarify which is correct

Comment: Sorry true blue anil, actually it is : $A$ and $B$ alternately throw a fair coin.

Comment: Well, following the same approach as in my answer, $\Bbb P$(A wins on first round) $=\frac12$

$\Bbb P$(A doesn't win on first round and B wins on second round) $=\frac12\cdot\frac12 = \frac14$

Odds in favor of A = $\frac12 : \frac14 = 2:1$

Thus $\Bbb P$(A wins) $= \frac2{2+1} = \frac23$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each throw **two coins** alternately (the more difficult formulation), one way to solve is to consider the **odds** for the first two rounds.
[ Subsequent rounds of $2$ will only add some common multiplier, **odds** won't change]

$\Bbb P$(A wins on first round) $=\frac14$

$\Bbb P$(A doesn't win on first round and B wins on second round) $=\frac34\cdot\frac14 = \frac3{16}$

Odds in favor of A = $\frac14 : \frac3{16} = 4:3$

Thus $\Bbb P$(A wins) $= \frac4{4+3} = \frac47$

Comment: lol, nice.${}{}{}$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo: Glad you like it !

Answer (score 1):

Change the game a bit to make it clearer, consider a reasonable probability space on the set of pairs of infinite sequences of $0$ and $1$ $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$.

Given such a sequence $(a_n)$ we can define the winning time $w(a_n)$ as the first $i$ such that $a_i=a_{i-1}=1$.

We want to find the probability $P(w(a_n)\leq w(b_n))$.

We can say it is $\frac{1}{2}+P(w(a_n)=w(b_n))$.

We say it is equal to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty P(w(a_n)=w(b_n))=k$.

We say this is equal to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty P(w(a_n))^2=k$

For $k\geq 3$ We have that $P(w(a_n))=k$ is $\frac{F_{k-3}}{2^k}$ because the number of sequences of length $n$ of $1$ and $0$ that end in $11$ and don't have any other $11$ is $F_{k-3}$

Where $F_n$ is the usual fibonacci sequence $F_0=1,F_1=1,F_2=2$ etc.

Now just plug in the usual formula for the fibonaccis to get:

$$\frac{1}{4}+\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty  \bigg (\frac{\frac{ (\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2})^{k-3} - (\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2} ) ^{k-3} }{\sqrt 5}}{2^k}\bigg )^2=\frac{1}{4}+\sum\limits_{k=3}^\infty  \frac{ ((\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2})^{k-3} - (\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2})^{k-3})^2 }{5\cdot2^{2k}}$$

I think from here it is clear that this splits into three geometric series

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your pattern is correct.  Notice that problem says that $A$ and $B$ toss *two* coins. I assume the game ends when one player flips the two coins and lands two heads. Also, I assume it's a fair coin and that throws are independent of each other. Let $A$ and $B$ be the events that the respective player ends the game.

Notice that $P(\bar B) = P(\bar A) = 1- P(A) = 1-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{4}.$

Generalizing the pattern that you found, we have
$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k} \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}.$$

Alternatively, let $p_A$ be the probability that $A$ wins the game. Notice that $A$ can win on the first try with probability $1/4$. If $A$ doesn't win, then $B$ takes a turn. If $B$ fails, he fails with probability $3/4$. Notice that after $B$ fails this first time, it's like the game "starts over". Then we have
$$p_A = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}p_A.$$
Solving for $p_A$ gives $\frac{4}{7}$.